# Excel: Printing all of the filters on a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

So, I have a pivot table, which I have named 'CSRTable' because I'm uncreative.  On this pivot table, it has a graph of sales for each of a rep (field called csr_name) for a set of weeks (field called WeekEnding)

Here's the Pivot Table, the data is pulled from the tab "Sale Raw", which is Sheet3 in the VBA: 
[image]

So that is my simple pivot table.  What the issue is, my boss has issued me a directive: to print once and it prints ALL of our "csr_name"  for the given WeekEnding.

I am unfamiliar with how to do this, I know there's a way to VBA it, but I haven't found a way that I have been able to work, this is t he only one that I have found:

```
Sub LoopField()
Dim pivF As PivotField
Dim pivI As PivotItem

Set pivF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CSRPivot").PivotFields("csr_name")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each pivI In pivF.PivotItems
    pivF.CurrentPage = pivI.Name

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Next pivI
 'Clear filer
pivF.ClearAllFilters

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But that doesn't work, it just prints the one (in this case Acevedo).

So, he wants to change the CSR_NAME, but not the WeekEnding and print each of them on a different page.   If the VBA is accidentally correct, here's where the location of it is, when I select the Pivot table and hit Alt+F11

[image]

Per QHarr I have in the comments,

```
Option Explicit
'Requires all items selected
Sub GetAllCSRItems()
    Const filePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\" 'save location for new files
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("CSRPivot")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim item As Variant
    Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("csr_name")
    pvtField.ClearAllFilters
    pvtField.CurrentPage = "(All)"

     For Each item In pvtField.PivotItems
        item.Visible = True
     Next item
    pvt.ShowPages "csr_name"
    For Each item In pvtField.PivotItems
        Dim newBook As Workbook
        Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
        With newBook
            .Worksheets(1).Name = item.Name
            wb.Worksheets(item.Name).UsedRange.Copy
            Worksheets(item.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
           .SaveAs Filename:=filePath & item.Name & ".xlsx"
           .Close
        End With
        Set newBook = Nothing
Next item
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each item In pvtField.PivotItems
         wb.Worksheets(item.Name).Delete
    Next item
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

into

[image]

and still got nothing from this result

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105924/6241235 may help or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429986/vba-loop-each-item-in-pivot-filter-and-paste-into-new-sheet Basically these demonstrate the effective showPages method as well as one solution that iterates through every selection.

Comment: @QHarr if those work, when I put them into my worksheet, I can't get them to do ANYTHING.  I of course have updated the information to match my sheet's but, still can't make anything work.

Comment: csr_name would have to be in the page field for the showPages method. I assure you those work in the questions context they pertain to.

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CSRPivot").ShowPages "csr_name" Making sure to run when in the right sheet and with csr_name in the page field area.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. It is illegible and comments may disappear. There is no loop with showPages. The command is a one liner as I gave above.... ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CSRPivot").ShowPages "csr_name"

Comment: See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5cC1n0_t2U

Comment: Updated the post with what I put in, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries :-) SO is for learning. At least you respond and update so +1

Comment: LOL thanks.  Where should I put that .ShowPages at, just at the bottom?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I put where the data is being pulled from in the OP.  "Sheet3 (Sale Raw)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172019/discussion-between-qharr-and-dragos-kai).

Comment: I have posted a version you may try.

Comment: @QHarr I went into chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and you should  be able to do something like the following.

**Note:**

We are exporting the sheet that contains the pivotchart as this looks better size wise in the pdf. Also, we have an additional sub to get rid of the generated pdfs that can be called separately.

---

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const filePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FolderToEmpty\"

Public Sub GetAllEmployeeSelections()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Print THIS TAB")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("CSRPivot")

    ws.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim item As Long, item2 As Long

    Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("csr_name")

    For item = 1 To pvtField.PivotItems.Count

          pvtField.PivotItems(item).Visible = True

          For item2 = 1 To pvtField.PivotItems.Count

              If item2 <> item Then pvtField.PivotItems(item2).Visible = False

          Next item2

          ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FILENAME:=filePath & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Replace(pvtField.PivotItems(item).Name, ";", "_")) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                                                   IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next item

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub

Public Sub ClearFolder()
    Dim f As Object, fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FolderExists(Left$(filePath, Len(filePath) - 1)) Then
        For Each f In fso.GetFolder(Left$(filePath, Len(filePath) - 1)).Files
            f.Delete Force:=True
        Next f
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added in the pdf line as well.