# Select first value in a pivot filter

Tags: excel, vba, loops

i have a mobile usage pivot with a mobile number filter that shows all numbers but this list keeps changing everytime i change the raw data, iam trying to create a macro to select the first mobile number  in the pivot filter to display the pivot data then save this sheet as a copy then select the next mobile number and loop through all filter numbers till its complete but i am having troubles as i am new to vba

Comment: This question already has numberous answers. One moment and I will find you a link to some. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299706/6241235 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431535/6241235

Comment: The first link is good but what if i just wanna select the first item in the pivot then save copy as and then do the same thing with the rest of the numbers

Comment: The first link showPages method, if the numbers field is in the pagefield of the pivottable, will loop each item and generate a sheet with that selection visible.

Comment: yes i have tried it and it works good but i dnt wanna get the usage of each number in a seperate sheet, i just wanna show the number in the same sheet then save copy of the sheet then loop through the whole list if possible

Comment: So when you loop each number what are you doing with the pivottable showing the view for the new number?

Comment: when i show the number the details of the usage its going to show up in the pivot then i am going to save the whole sheet as copy in a folder, as if im creating a usage summary for each number in a separate workbook.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105924/6241235

Comment: here we go , finally its working :), its only saving the pivot range, i am trying to save the whole sheet

Comment: should i change pvt.TableRange2.Copy to WorkSheets.("Charge Summary").Copy

Comment: I haven't  tested but something like https://pastebin.com/3nD2tqhG

Comment: Thanks QHarr, its all up and running now , really appreciated

Comment: you  are welcome :-)